# Why doesn't DateTime.ParseExact work for this example outside of the US?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a string:

```
var stringDate = "8/19/2016 5:00:00 PM"
```

and I try using:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate,"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null);
```

or

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
                                   CultureInfo.Invariant);
```

or

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate,"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                                   CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
```

It works fine if the machine is in the US but and for all 3 options I get the following error when running from a machine in London:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can see, you need to use [`h` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hSpecifier) instead of [`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier) since your hour part does not have leading zero for single digit values.

```
var stringDate = "8/19/2016 5:00:00 PM";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

Also I would suggest to use *specific* culture settings instead of `null` for any case. In your example, since `null` means `CurrentCulture` settings for `DateTime` parsing methods, your `CurrentCulture` settings;

- May not use `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator) or
- May not use `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator) or
- May not use [`GregorianCalendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar) as a [`Calendar` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.calendar) or
- May not have `AM` or `PM` as a [`PMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator) or [`AMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator) properties.

For those, your `ParseExact` method throws exception *even* if your string and format perfectly matches.

Comment: So this code above works fine when i run it on a server in the US (so it definitely fixed part of the issue) but if i run the same code with the same string on a machine in London and I still get the same error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: @leora Are you using `InvariantCulture` in your code or `null` or `CurrentCulture`? If you use `InvariantCulture`, it shouldn't be any error. What is the `CurrentCulture` of the machine in London for example?

Comment: this is what i am using (that isn't working)                 var value =DateTime.ParseExact(StartDateTime,"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  How do i find out the "currentculture" of the machine?

Comment: @leora If this code won't work, I'm quite sure your `StartDateTime` is **not** `8/19/2016 5:00:00 PM`. If you wanna check the current culture, go to regional settings on it. Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Overrides